# Webpack2 loading and extracting LESS file

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

I am trying to setup Webpack2 to process my LESS files and create a separate CSS from it. I keep getting an error however. I've had trouble locating Webpack2 examples outlining the process so not sure what I am missing.

My Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'public': [
      './src/client/styles/public.js'
    ]
  },
  output: {
   ...
  },
  module: {
      {
       test: /.*\.less$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ loader: 'less-loader', fallbackLoader: 'style-loader' })
      }
    ]

  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: '[name].css', disable: false, allChunks: true })
  ]
}
```

The `public.js` file (I also tried passing the less file directly to entry with same result):

```
require('style.less')
```

The `style.less` file

```
a { color: red; }
```

The Error:

```
ERROR in ./~/less-loader!./src/client/styles/style.less
Module parse failed: /node_modules/less-loader/index.js!/src/client/styles/style.less Unexpected token (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| a {
|   color: red;
| }
```

It appears from the message that the less loader is correctly being passed the file but breaks. I've tried a blank file but then I get:

```
TypeError: text.forEach is not a function
```

Versions:

```
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
"less": "^2.7.1",
"less-loader": "^2.2.3",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.25",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.5",
"yargs": "~3.5.4"
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.. got it working with:

```
 loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ 
     loader:[ 'css', 'less' ], 
     fallbackLoader: 'style-loader' 
 })
```

**Edit** This was for Webpack v2 - thanks to @thelastshadow for note on Webpack 4  issue [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/701).

Comment: So... by using an additional loader.

Comment: @Quotidian yes. It's the webpack2 config that is throwing me off. You can post this in your answer and I will mark it.

Comment: Webpack is a file bundler/loader so it may be confusing that one will have to extract the stuff that is gathered using a separate plugin.

Comment: I am going to make the argument that fall backloader isn't needed when using the extractTextPlugin

Comment: loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
            loader: [
               {
                  loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
              }, {
                  loader: "less-loader" // compiles Less to CSS
              }
            ],
        })

Comment: Just a note that ExtractTextPlugin doesn't work with webpack 4+ https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/701

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps also need to use an additional load like the style- or css-loaders. From the [Docs](https://github.com/webpack/less-loader):

```
var css = require("!raw!less!./file.less");
// => returns compiled css code from file.less, resolves imports
var css = require("!css!less!./file.less");
// => returns compiled css code from file.less, resolves imports and url(...)s
```

The less-loader just handles the processing into CSS. Webpack then needs to know how to incorporate the CSS before it's extracted back out.

Comment: Isn't that what the fallbackLoader does?

Comment: I've never seen the `fallbackLoader` option before, so I'm not sure. I would suspect not; a fallback would only be used if the real loaders couldn't process/weren't found. Akin to how resolve.fallback works.

Comment: so is the style-loader a "fallback"?